# sql more than one keys in one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I guess, the name of the question is strange, but I don't know how to state it correctly, so I'll try to describe the problem. Say, we have two tables:

1)

```
id | unit_name | strength | health
1  | private   | 10       | 10
2  | general   | 5        | 5
n  | someone   | 123      | 321
```

2)

```
id | rules | who_has_this_rule
1  | rule1 | 1
2  | rule2 | 2
3  | rule3 | 1
4  | rule4 | 1
```

The field "who_has_this_rule" correspondes with id of the first table.
But I can't figure out what to do if a unit should have more than one rule in his profile. For example, private should have rule1 and rule4. How to do this?

Comment: It's a lot better to call the column that references another table something related to that table's name, like `unit_id` instead of `who_has_this_rule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a join table.

A third table to join rule and units

unit_rules

```
id | unit_id | rule_id
1  |  1      | 1
2  |  1      | 4
3  |  2      | 1
```

You can have a primary key(id) or compound key(unit_id and rule_id)

Comment: Thank you. And what if two (or more) units should have the same rule?

Comment: Then you have another row in the join table that says, for example, `id: 3, unit_id: 1, rule_id: 4`